# Xiomara CTF 2018, 23 February 2018 at 17:00 UTC, lasts 24 hours

Tags: discussion, ctf

Let's participate in [Xiomara CTF 2018](http://xiomara.xyz/).

---

Xiomara is a Jeopardy-style CTF and lasts 24 hours. You can find additional details on the [CTFtime event page](https://ctftime.org/event/580) and study the write-ups of the 2017 edition [here](https://ctftime.org/event/430/tasks/).

General info :

- We compete as team secse.
- We communicate over [Slack](https://sec-ctf.slack.com/). To get an invitation to the group you can contact any member of the team. (We will need to know an email address to send the invitation to and a reference to your Security.SE profile.)
- For questions, join us in the [public chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151/the-dmz).

Good luck everyone!

---

The team ranked 70th out of 240 teams, with 401 points.

Due to network errors from our side and also from Xiomara's website, we decided to put all our efforts on [NeverLAN CTF 2018](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2900/76718), which was on the same date.