# Pragyan CTF 2018, 2 March 2018 at 07:30 UTC, lasts 48 hours

Tags: discussion, ctf

Let's participate in [Pragyan CTF 2018](https://ctf.pragyan.org/home).

Pragyan CTF is a Jeopardy-style CTF and lasts 48 hours. Challenges are from a range of categories like Cryptography, Web, Forensics, Steganography, Reverse Engineering, Binary Exploits, etc.

You can find additional details on the [CTFtime event page](https://ctftime.org/event/581) and study the write-ups of the 2017 edition [here](https://ctftime.org/event/420/tasks/).

---

General info:

- We compete as team sec.se.
- We communicate over [Slack](https://sec-ctf.slack.com/). To get an invitation to the group you can contact any member of the team. (We will need to know an email address to send the invitation to and a reference to your Security.SE profile.)
- For questions, join us in the [public chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151/the-dmz).

Good luck everyone!

---

The team ranked 61st out of 1300 teams, with 1450 points. Congratulations everyone!

Comment: I'll join with great pleasure :)

Comment: It was a pleasure \o/

Comment: Just wanted to add this for whoever thought about joining the team, but felt he/she maybe couldn't provide enough experience/knowledge/whatever: I felt the same but joined anyway. The outcome: It was a ton of fun, I learned a lot, and I was able to provide starting points for a solution and even a solution myself. I had no idea about most of this stuff, but I was able to acquire the needed knowledge within the given time. All the other guys on the team were very helpful and just by reading what they were talking about, I learned a lot. Highly recommend this!